# NGAdmin don't load some APIRest requests (Symfony)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony, ng-admin

I'm using NGAdmin with Symfony and I have created a RESTful API to work whith it. It works fine, but when I have to load a list or a create/edit form that has a field whith relationships, it doesn,t load some of this relations.

It's completely random. For example, if a form has "category" and "province" fields (whith their relationships with their respective tables), sometimes doesn't load the categories, sometimes doesn't load the provinces, sometimes doesn't load both, sometimes load both and works fine...

I think my code is ok, because if it had some problems, it would never work fine. But it must fail somewhere. If I make proves in Postman for example, it works fine always.

Here is a capture with the request in the Chrome's developer tools. If anyone can have an idea of the cause, I would appreciate.

[image]

[image]